# Laravel's ui:auth command generating incompatible Controllers

Tags: laravel

I have a Laravel installation on v7.29.3 (our server won't support v8 yet)

I am having an issue with the `ui:auth` command. It is generating Controllers that reference classes in the `Illuminate` namespace that don't exist.

For example, the `Auth\VerificationController` class it gives me, uses `Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\VerifiesEmails` but I can't see a corresponding file in the `/vendor/laravel/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Auth` directory.

What's more, when I search for "VerifiesEmails" in the Laravel API doc for v7.x there is no such file. This file does exist however when I search for it in v6.x

So my guess is that I've got a mismatch somewhere and I'm getting v6 controllers for a v7 installation.

However, composer is showing that I have `laravel/ui` 2.5 which is supposed to be for Laravel 7.

I've tried deleting my composer.lock and vendor directories and reinstalling from composer in the hope that would clear up the issue, but no dice.

Any ideas what could be going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those classes aren't in `vendor/laravel/framework/src/...`. They are not part of the framework. They come from the `laravel/ui` package, `vendor/laravel/ui/auth-backend/...`.

Comment: Ahhhhhhhhhh OK, that makes sense. Or at least, a kind of sense - it's not very intuitive namespacing but I suppose its to aid compatibility. Thanks for your help!